# Context Api state not updating

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Hey I have this function in AuthContext.js

```
    let [authTokens, setAuthTokens] = useState(null)
    let [user, setUser] = useState(false)
    let [failedlogin, setFailedlogin] = useState(false)

    let loginUser = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        let response = await fetch(URL, {
            method:'POST',
            headers:{
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body:JSON.stringify({'email':e.target.email.value, 'password':e.target.password.value})
        })
        let data = await response.json()
        if(response.ok) {
            setAuthTokens(data)
            localStorage.setItem('authTokens', JSON.stringify(data))
            setUser(true)
            router.push('/dashboard')
        } else {
            setFailedlogin(true)
        }
    }
```

Then in a differnet component im using it like so

```
import { StyledLogin } from "./Styles/Login.Styles.Js"
import Link from 'next/link'
import React, {useContext, useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import AuthContext from '../context/AuthContext'

const LoginComponent = () => {

  let { loginUser, failedlogin } = useContext(AuthContext);
  

  return (
    <StyledLogin>
      <div className="container">
        <div className="form-container">
          <form onSubmit={loginUser}>
            {failedlogin && <h1>Email or Password is incorrect</h1>}
            <div className="input-container">
              <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
              <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" />
            </div>
            <div className="login-button">
              <button>Sign In</button>
            </div>
          </form>
          <div className="create-account">
            <Link href="/signup">
              <button>Create Account</button>
            </Link>
          </div>
          <Link href="/forgot-password">
            <p className="forgot">Forgot your password?</p>
          </Link>
        </div>
      </div>
    </StyledLogin>
  );
}

export default LoginComponent
```

When the **loginUser** function runs it updates the states but in the second component the **failedLogin** doesn't change

Im passing in all the states to contextData, the loginUser function user works as well but the failedlogin state doesnt get updated into the second component

The entire app is wrapped in the context api like so:

```
import '../styles/globals.css'
import Layout from '../components/Layout'
import { AuthProvider } from '../context/AuthContext'

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <AuthProvider>
      <Layout>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </Layout>
    </AuthProvider>
  )
}

export default MyApp
```

Comment: can we see the "second component"?

Comment: @IonutAchim included the entire second component in edit

Comment: I see a single component using the context, there is no "second component". Or maybe you're referring to `LoginComponent` as the "second component" because you consider the "first component" to be something else, is that the case?

Comment: @IonutAchim i was considering Authcontext as the first component (probably not that i think about it). Authcontext is wrapped around every component

Comment: have you checked your console? One thing I'm guessing might be the culprit is the fact that you're trying to parse the response before checking if it's ok - usually when the response is not ok the response body is `null` (unless you specifically design your API differently) and trying to parse it will throw an error and the rest of your code won't run

Comment: Can you show the full code for the `AuthContext.js` file?

Answer (score 0):

Propably your "second component" is not wrapped in the same ContextProvider or is outside that provider.

Comment: I dont believe so, as the **loginUser** function works in the same component but not **failedlogin**

Comment: Can you share then more code? Component 1, Component 2, how do you wrap the context and whole code of context.js?